# Необходима помощь с Coroutine Android MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

Знакомлюсь с Coroutines и пока не пойму как получить данные из database типа LiveData.
**ViewModel**

```
class AddTimeLessonsViewModel @Inject constructor(val repository: DataRepository) : ViewModel(){
    private val timeLessons = getAllTimeLesson()

    fun getAllTimeLesson(): LiveData<List<TimeLesson>>{
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            //вот тут, как получить. Следующий код не работает
            return repository.getTimeLesson()
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Singleton
class DataRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val appDatabase : AppDatabase
){
    private val timeLessons = map(
        appDatabase.getTimeLessonDao().getAllTimeLesson()){ timeLessons ->
        return@map timeLessons.map {it.toTimeLesson()}

    }

    fun getTimeLesson() : LiveData<List<TimeLesson>> {
        return timeLessons
    }

}
```

**Dao**

```
@Dao
interface TimeLessonDao{

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(vararg timeLessonEntities : TimeLessonEntity)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM time_lesson ORDER BY start_time ASC")
    fun getAllTimeLesson(): LiveData<List<TimeLessonEntity>>
}
```

Некоторые люди писали, что необходимо вместо viewModelScope.launch использовать viewModelScope.async, но тогда repository.getTimeLesson() должен иметь тип Deffered.

И я вот не пойму на какой стадии (Repository, Dao) мне нужно иметь тип Deffered, и вообще как сохранить LiveData, ведь мы наблюдаем за данными.

Подскажите, как поправить, кто по опытней и использовал Coroutine в MVVM

Comment: Корутина должна быть там, где LiveData заполняется данными.

Comment: @Evgene, т.е когда берем из бд?

Comment: У вас там два вида LiveData, одни данные из Room, потом вы их перегоняете в другой. Я не вижу всего решения, но возможно из Room лучше получать просто данные, которые в корутине дождетесь и переведете в LiveData с преобразованием.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja ну ладно, допустим я оберну в Defered<List<Entity>> на уровня repository, как мне получить то данные в корутинах? return repository.getTimeLesson() не работает, return repository.getTimeLesson().await не работает

Comment: Вот тут все расписано: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata

Comment: Не пойму  зачем вам лайвдата ейсли вы не подписываетесь на изменения в ней. Если Вам просто нужно с рум получить данные при запросе, то используйте асинк. и возвращайте в свою переменную. Если же хотите подпсываться на изменения в руме, то тогда подпишитель вашу лайвдату и получайте данные уже когда произойдут изменения в даных либо при инициализации.

Comment: Добавил вариант реализации. Но @EugeneKrivenja сделал резонное замечание относительно того, что нет достатоного количества данных, чтобы более детально разобраться с Вашей проблемой.

Comment: Если нет подписки на ливдату, то тогда она не нужна абсолютно и можно обойтись курутинами.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать `runBlocking` и `async`. Потом при помощи `.await()` зупушить в Вашу переменную результат запроса. Ниже пример кода адаптированого под Вашу версию:

```
class AddTimeLessonsViewModel @Inject constructor(val repository: DataRepository) : ViewModel(){
    private val timeLessons = getAllTimeLesson()

    fun getAllTimeLesson(): LiveData<List<TimeLesson>> = runBlocking {

        val mDeferredResult = async {

           repository.getTimeLesson()

        }

        mDeferredResult.await() 
    }
}
```

НО!! согласно того кода который у Вас в вопросе, то Вы хотите получить список в `LiveData<List<TimeLesson>>`. Кода, где Вы используете результаты которые пришли в переменную `private val timeLessons` Вы не показали. Потому предполагаю что Вы уже знаете как потом получать с `LiveData<List<TimeLesson>>` простой `List<TimeLesson>`.